# mass merge accounts - tool suggestion anyone?

Tags: account, record, merge

We have 2 sets of accounts in one org and would like to merge them. They are currently separated by Account Record Types, so I'm really asking if there is a way to merge 2 record types into one. We'd like to merge any duplicates found.

Anyone know of a tool that does something like this? We have ~ 200k in one record type and another ~ 300k in another record type, trying to automate as much as we can.

Many thanks,

Paul

Comment: Could you use data loader to  extract all the records you want to change, update the recordtypeId to reflect the new Id, then re-upload them back into SF?

Comment: Are any of the record types Person Accounts?

Comment: Yes, there are Business and Person accounts on both Records Types.
I'd like to mass merge duplicates as there are a lot. Changing recordtypeid wouldn't achieve that. 
Thanks for the replies

Comment: I'm not certain that their tool will do what you want, but DemandTools is the most powerful deduping tool I've used.  It's worth checking in to depending on your budget for this.

https://www.validity.com/demandtools/

Comment: Thank you, I will review DemandTools. Was not aware of them.